# C# Printing a 2D Array in Matrix Format Using a Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I am trying to create an array that will print out times tables. The first column is the 1 times table, the second is the 2 times table and so on.  The user is asked for an input that will determine the number of rows and columns.
I want to print the array in matrix format using a foreach loop. It works fine when I use a for loop but I would like to know how to achieve the same output using a foreach loop.

Shown is the code:

```
int rows;
int columns;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows");
rows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of columns");
columns = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] multiDim = new int[rows, columns];

for (int p = 0; p < multiDim.GetLength(0); p++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < multiDim.GetLength(1); k++)
    {
       multiDim[p, k] = (p + 1) * (k + 1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();            
}

foreach (int i in multiDim)
    {
        Console.Write(i + " ");

        if (i == multiDim.GetLength(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

When I enter a value for rows that is above 2 the program does does not print the array in a proper array format. For example when I have 3 rows and 5 columns the output is:

1    2    3    4    5

2    4    6    8    10
3    6    9    12    15

I have read similar questions bu they do not seem to help. All help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Camilo Your edit didn't help my question. I got an output which I showed. Do you get the correct output when you run the code?

Comment: Oops, sorry, thought that was unintentional, as formatting is not the easiest on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looping over the values of the array, rather than the indexes. This means that it just happens to work initially since your values line up well.

I would suggest switching to using [Jagged Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) instead of Multidimensional arrays. This way you can do `foreach (row in multiDim)`, then `foreach (cell in row)`

If you still need to use a multidimensional array, then you need some form of counter which keeps track of the position of the array you are in. This is why a regular for loop is better to use for this scenario rather than a foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. Can explain why my original code didn't give the desired output?

Comment: You were only printing a new line if `i` was equal to `multiDim.GetLength(1)`. In your code, when `i` was `10`, it didn't print a new line, it only printed one when it was `5`

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was evaluating the index, but I was really evaluating the value?

Comment: I just realised that `i` was the value of the array, not an index. So my answer is not actually correct. I'll edit my post with that detail in.